# Rails Ajax Refresh Breaks Modal Upload Form Submit

Tags: ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal, submit-button

I have a list of items that gets refreshed on create and update, I have a form that allows you to add elements, remove, adjust pricing inline. If you'd like to edit whom the task is assigned to, it pops up a modal which contains a partial with the form once again but to edit the object. Everything works fine and refreshes as it should.

**The Problem**
On the same line I have a paperclip and a camera that also open up modals that contain forms to upload a document or click camera to upload a picture. These work fine from the page if it's on load but after an ajax refresh the submit buttons will not work.

**The Code**

Index Partial:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <% if work_order.tasks.any? %>
        <ul class="task-table">
            <% work_order.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
            <li class="row task-table-row">

                <%= bootstrap_form_for(task, remote:true) do |f| %>
                    <%= render(partial:'tasks/task', locals:{task:task, f:f, index: index}) %>
                <% end %>

            </li>
            <%= render(partial:'work_orders/modal_forms', locals:{task:task, index:index}) %>
            <%= render(partial:'tasks/attachments', locals:{task:task, index: index}) %>
            <%= render(partial:"tasks/edit", locals:{task:task, index:index})%>
            <% end %>
            <li class="row">
                <div class="table-total">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 column">
                        <div id="total-wrap">
                            <h3>Est. total:  <span id="subTotal"></span></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <% else %>
        <li class="row task-table-row">
            No tasks currently exist.
        </li>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button-margin">
    <%= render(partial:'tasks/new', locals:{work_order:work_order})%>
</div>
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
<%= link_to "Mark as Complete", work_order_path(work_order, work_order:{completed: true}), class:"btn btn-block btn-danger btn-outline b-r-xs", method: :put, remote:true %>
```

Task partial:

```
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="pull-right column inline">
        <p class="assign inline"><small class="text-muted">
            <% if task.assignable_id.present? %>
            <%= truncate(task.assignable.name, length:7) %>
            <% else %>
            assign
            <% end %>
        </small></p>
        <a href="#" class="text-muted inline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal<%= index %>">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <p class="inline"><%= truncate(task.location, length:20) %></p>
</div>

<% if task.labor.present? && task.materials.present? %>

<!-- if labor or materials are both available -->
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= link_to work_order_task_path(task.work_order, task, task:{labor:nil}), method: :put, remote:true, class:" text-muted pull-right" do %><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><% end%>
    <p class="inline pull-right">
        <span class="text-success currency"><%= number_to_currency(task.labor) %></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= link_to work_order_task_path(task.work_order, task, task:{materials:nil}), method: :put, remote:true, class:" text-muted pull-right" do %><i class=" fa fa-pencil"></i><% end%>
    <p class="inline pull-right">
        <span class="text-success currency"><%= number_to_currency(task.materials) %></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 column task" data-task="<%= task.id%>">

    <a id="deleteTask">
        <i class="fa fa-remove text-danger pull-right" > </i>
    </a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal<%= index %>">
        <i class="fa fa-camera text-success pull-right"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="text-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#attachmentModal<%= index %>">
        <i class="fa fa-paperclip pull-right"></i>
    </a>

    <% if task.task_photos.any? || task.attachments.any? %>
    <a class="text-green" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#attachments<%= index %>" tooltip="View Attachments">
        <i class="fa fa-eye pull-right" > </i>
    </a>
    <% end %>

</div>

<% elsif task.labor.blank? && task.materials.present? %>
<!-- Else if labor is blank and materials are present -->
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= f.text_field :labor, hide_label:true, prepend: "$", append: ".00", placeholder:"Est. Labor" %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= link_to work_order_task_path(task.work_order, task, task:{materials:nil}), method: :put, remote:true, class:" text-muted pull-right" do %><i class=" fa fa-pencil"></i><% end%>
    <p class="inline pull-right">
        <span class="text-success currency"><%= number_to_currency(task.materials) %></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 column task" data-task="<%= task.id%>">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn btn-outline btn-success b-r-xs submitTask pull-right" %>
</div>

<% elsif task.materials.blank? && task.labor.present? %>
<!-- Else if materials is blank and labor is present -->
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= link_to work_order_task_path(task.work_order, task, task:{labor:nil}), method: :put, remote:true, class:" text-muted pull-right" do %><i class=" fa fa-pencil"></i><% end%>
    <p class="inline pull-right">
        <span class="text-success currency"><%= number_to_currency(task.labor) %></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= f.text_field :materials, hide_label:true, prepend: "$", append: ".00", placeholder:"Est. Material" %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 column task" data-task="<%= task.id%>">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn btn-outline btn-success b-r-xs submitTask pull-right" %>
</div>

<% else %>
<!-- Else materials and labor are both blank -->
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= f.text_field :labor, hide_label:true, prepend: "$", append: ".00", placeholder:"Est. Labor" %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 column">
    <%= f.text_field :materials, hide_label:true, prepend: "$", append: ".00", placeholder:"Est. Material" %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 column task" data-task="<%= task.id%>">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn btn-outline btn-success b-r-xs submitTask pull-right" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

The Modals That Wont Submit

```
<!-- attachments modal -->
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="attachmentModal<%= index %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Attach Documents</h4>
                <small class="font-bold">Upload quotes, sales orders, receipts and invoices.</small>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <%= bootstrap_form_for [task, Attachment.new] do |f| %>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <%= f.text_field :name %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <%= f.text_field :amount, prepend: "$", append: ".00", label:"Total (optional)" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <%= f.file_field :file %>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <%= f.submit "Add Attachment", class:"btn btn-primary btn-outline b-r-xs" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end attachments modal -->

<!-- images modal -->
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="imageModal<%= index %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Attach Images</h4>
                <small class="font-bold">Upload images and descriptions.</small>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="target">
                </div>
                <%= bootstrap_form_for [task, TaskPhoto.new] do |f| %>

                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.hidden_field :property_manager_id, value:current_manager.id %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_field :description %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-outline b-r-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <%= f.submit "Add Photo", class:"btn btn-primary btn-outline b-r-xs" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end images modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that having the submit in my modal footer was causing the error.

Although it works just fine on initial page load, it was causing error when it was refreshed by ajax. Moving the submit button into the modal-body with the rest of my form fixed my problem.

Hope this helps someone in the future!